# 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert one column str type to datetime type. But when I write the code:

```
df.timeStamp = df.timeStamp.to_datetime
```

it just tell me

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'
```

But when I try

```
pd.to_datetime(df.timeStamp)
```

it works.

I am new to python and hope someone could explain why it happens.

I appreciate your time!

Comment: What's the point, it's just simply that `to_datetime` belongs to `pd`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because `to_datetime` is only a valid attribute to `pandas` module, that's all.

So that's why:

`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'`

(see highlighted part)

So of course, `to_datetime` can't be used that way.

Comment: Thank you! Does that means the attributes of pandas are not same with the attributes of a dataframe? I just thought a pandas type data should inherited all the attributes from pandas module

Answer (score 23):

I am kind of late, but still useful for future readers.

Below code converts a column of type **object** in a pandas df to type **timestamp**

```
df.timeStamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timeStamp)
```